# XSLT match parent and child

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML and I wanna extract all **title_en** attributes.

```
<quiz>
    <question title_de="Seit wann wird Appenzeller® Käse hergestellt?" 
              title_fr="Depuis quand le fromage d’Appenzell est-il fabriqué?" 
              title_en="For how long has Appenzeller cheese been made?" >
        <answer title_de="Über 7 Jahre!" title_fr="Depuis plus de 7 ans !" title_en="For over 7 years !"></answer>
        <answer title_de="Über 70 Jahre!" title_fr="Depuis plus de 70 ans !" title_en="For over 70 years !"></answer>
        <answer title_de="Über 700 Jahre!" title_fr="Depluis plus de 700 ans !" title_en="For over 700 years !"></answer>
    </question>
 </quiz>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="answer">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/></td>
    </tr>        
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="question">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/></td>
    </tr>        
  </xsl:template>
```

Either I can get the attributes from question or from answer, but never from both. I've tried all kind of match statements

Comment: You're not calling `xsl:apply-templates` from within the template for `question`, so the `answer` elements will never get processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to only have included a part of your XSLT, perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/quiz">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="question"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="answer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="question">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="answer"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think you are just missing the `<xsl:apply-templates select="answer"/>` from the question template. You will need to modify the HTML, as this now outputs TR tags inside the question TD as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>For how long has Appenzeller cheese been made?<tr>
            <td>For over 7 years !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>For over 70 years !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>For over 700 years !</td>
        </tr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: right, I was a bit short there :-(
But the 2nd <xsl:apply-templates select="answer"/> did it.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="quiz">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="question[@title_en]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="question/answer"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="answer">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="question">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title_en"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```